# How to create dynamic array element names in JavaScript, inside a for loop?

Tags: javascript, arrays, concatenation

I have a for loop in a JS snippet and I want to dynamically generate the array members' names, based on a string and the current iteration number. Basically I have written something like this:

```
product_data[i] = {
  "ch-" + i: '1',
  'product' + i: jsondata[products][i].product_description,
  'quantity' + i: jsondata[products][i].quantity,
  'price' + i: jsondata[products][i].unit_price,
  'rem' + i: '',
  'fpa' + i: jsondata[products][i].vat
};
```

however, it's not working at all. I've used `eval()` without any luck too. Any ideas?

Comment: Provide complete jsondata json, so we can help

Comment: Before we give you the answer, are you sure you want to do that?  When dealing with arrays you deal with a list of the same types.  if you are going to change it such that each indexed item has a different set of keys, maybe there is a different way.

Comment: Create it as an object then you can use stringify()

Comment: @DmitryYudin I don't believe the json data are necessary. It could be something as simple as the iteration number itself.

Comment: I'm a bit wary of this approach also. Perhaps storing an (unique?) id in the object hash would be a simpler approach.

Comment: @Fallenreaper Unfortunately I need to use an existing set of var names and programming style, and I'm afraid that this is a quite quick, yet nasty way to do it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If supported in your environment, you can use the new ECMAScript notation for [computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names) in object initializers:

```js
var product_data = new Array(2);

for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
  product_data[i] = {
    ["ch-" + i]: i,
  };
}

console.log(product_data);
```

Otherwise, you can use good ol' [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation), like so:

```js
var product_data = new Array(2);

for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
  product_data[i] = {};
  product_data[i]["ch-" + i] = i;
}

console.log(product_data);
```

Answer (score 1):

This features exists since ES6. You can use it like so:

```
var obj = {
  [myKey]: value,
}
```

So your example becomes:

```
product_data[i] = {
               ["ch-" + i]: '1',
               ['product' + i]: jsondata[products][i].product_description,
               ['quantity' + i]: jsondata[products][i].quantity,
               ['price' + i]: jsondata[products][i].unit_price,
               ['rem' + i]: '',
               ['fpa' + i]: jsondata[products][i].vat
               };
```

If you want to don't want to use EcmaScript 6, you'll have to initialize your object as an empty one and then add the properties to it:

```
product_data[i] = {};
product_data[i]["ch-" + i] = '1'
...
```

Comment: Thank you also for your answer! Left upvote, but I have too small rep yet to be recorded ;)

Answer (score -1):

You can do it like this

```
product_data[i] = {};
product_data[i]["ch-"+i] = '1';
product_data[i]["product"+i] = jsondata[products][i].product_description;
...
```

And so on...